# How to Remove the User Id and/or Device Id/info from User Id from App Center Push SDK

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, visual-studio-app-center-push

I have added the UserId (email) in app center sdk using AppCenter.SetUserId("your-user-id");
Now I want to remove these userid from app center sdk. I am not seeing any method for this.

Also, As per my understanding whenever we add user using AppCenter.SetUserId("your-user-id"), it mapped some user device information like device unique id to user id. So I wanted to remove these device from specific userId in App Center Push notification. Thanks

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

you could refer to the [App Center Api](https://openapi.appcenter.ms/)

and check the `Delete` method,is this interface https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/account/users_removeFromOrg what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try `AppCenter.SetUserId("")` to unset it.